# Spring-boot - REST - Inconveniente informando errores en microservicios

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

Soy bastante nuevo en esto de los microservicios. Tengo 2 microservicios, el microservicio A y el microservicio B. En cierto momento, el microservicio A invoca a al microservicio B, realizando una llamada con RestTemplate, hasta aqui no hay ningun problema. El inconveniente se presenta cuando, por algun motivo, el microservicio B presenta un inconveniente y lanza una exception (cualquiera). El microservicio A se entera de esto porque recibe una respuesta que solamente dice statuscode 500 (internal server error) y un mensaje null...es decir que no sabe que fue lo que falló.
Mi solucion fue, en el microservicio B crear un ControllerAdvice para que todas las exceptions pasen por ahi y entonces yo retorno un JSON con un codigo de error custom y un mensaje. Entonces en el microservicio A parseo dicho JSON y ahi puedo saber qué sucedió...pero el inconveniente es que en el microservicio B el httpstatus tiene que ser OK...y eso no me gusta...porque no es OK sino que hubo errores, se entiende?. Les dejo algo de codigo para puedan entender un poco mas.

Microservicio A:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> callB(@RequestParam("parameters") String parameters, @RequestHeader (name="Authorization") String token) {

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.set("Authorization", token);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("parameters", parameters);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
 = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

DataResponse data = new RestTemplate().postForObject("http://localhost:5000/v1/api/interfases/process", requestEntity, DataResponse.class);

if (data.code == 200)
    return ResponseEntity.ok(data);         //todo OK
else {  //Hubo errores
    throw new Exception(data.description);
}
}
```

Microservicio B

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> process(@RequestParam("parameters") String parameters) throws Exception {
    //throw new Exception("Error producido en el microservicio");  //Lo hago fallar a proposito para ver que sucede
}
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class MsResponseExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<?> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    DataResponse data = new DataResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), "Se produjo un error inesperado. Contácte al administrador.", details);
    return new ResponseEntity(data, HttpStatus.OK);    // ----> ESTO ES MENTIRA NO DEBIERA SER OK
}
```

}

Si se fijan en la antepenultima linea, tengo que devolver un httpstatus OK porque sino el microservicio A solo se entera que falló pero no le llega el mensaje (Clase DataResponse que solo tiene un campo code y un campo description)
Existe algun mecanismo mas transparente que me pueda ayudar a conocer que pasa en cada microservicio desde el lado del invocador???. Gracias

Comment: Podrias intentar implementar tu propio [ResponseErrorHandler como en esta tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling).

Comment: Lo vi, pero si mal no entendí con ese mecanismo solamente sé que, por ejemplo, no se encontró "algo"...pero no tengo detalles de lo que realmente sucedió porque no me deja personalizar el mensaje de la exception. Ejemplo, si mi microservicio busca en 2 o 3 tablas yo no podría saber si el fallo fue buscando A, buscando B o buscando C y eso es justamente lo que quiero...quiero indicar lo mas detallado posible el error o inconveniente que hubo.